# Efecto JS Smooth Scroll me oculta la información debajo del Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, navbar

Estoy trabajando una pagina web estilo one page y ando creando un efecto de scroll suave el cual funciona muy bien cuando se le da clic en una etiqueta `a` con un ID, lo que pasa es que el header tiene una posición fixed y el contenido cuando se le da clic queda dabajo del header.

Necesito que cuando se le de el clic la información siempre este debajo del header.

El Header tiene un largo total de 13vh.

```js
//JQUERY EFECTO SCROLL

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Logre dar con la solución con el siguiente `script`

```js
$('.right li a, #menu-mobile-tiempos li a, .services-tiempos a').click(function () {

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);

        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 93
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Modificando la propiedad `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 93` y restando el valor que necesitaba.